# JavaScript function receives two strings and returns n

Tags: javascript, substring, logic

I've been trying to complete this challenge recently but with no success, tried many ways but 
for some reason I don't manage to complete all the examples below.

I will be appreciated if someone can assist me with that, showing me step by step.

> Write a function that receives two strings and returns n, where n is
>   equal to the number of characters we should shift the first string
>   forward to match the second. For instance, take the strings "fatigue"
>   and "tiguefa". In this case, the first string has been rotated 5
>   characters forward to produce the second string, so 5 would be
>   returned.
>
> If the second string isn't a valid rotation of the first string, the
>   method returns -1. Specification shiftedDiff(first, second) provide
>   amount of rotations to match words
>
> Parameters first: String - word to be matched
>
> second: String - word to be checked
>
> Return Value Number - Number of rotations, nil or -1 if invalid
>
> Examples:

- "coffee", "eecoff" => 2
- "eecoff", "coffee" => 4
- "moose", "Moose" => -1
- "isn't", "'tisn" => 2
- "Esham", "Esham" => 0
- "dog", "god" => -1

Comment: Show us your attempt(s) please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function shiftedDiff(first, second) {

  // Split the second word into an array for
  // easier manipulation
  const arr = [...second];

  // Iterate over the array
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    // If the first and joined array match
    // return the index
    if (first === arr.join('')) return i;

    // Otherwise `shift` off the first element of `arr`
    // and `push` it on the end of the array
    arr.push(arr.shift());
  }

  // If there are no matches return -1
  return -1;
}

console.log(shiftedDiff('coffee', 'eecoff')); // 2
console.log(shiftedDiff('eecoff', 'coffee')); // 4
console.log(shiftedDiff('moose', 'Moose')); // -1
console.log(shiftedDiff("isn't", "'tisn")); // 2
console.log(shiftedDiff('Esham', 'Esham')); // 0
console.log(shiftedDiff('dog', 'god')); // -1
```

#### Documentation

- [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let shiftedDiff = (f, s) => {
    let r = -1;
    f.split('').forEach((e, i) => {
        f = f.substr(1) + e;
        if (f == s) r = f.length - (i + 1)
    })
    return r;
}

console.log(shiftedDiff("coffee", "eecoff"))
console.log(shiftedDiff("eecoff", "coffee"))
console.log(shiftedDiff("moose", "Moose"))
console.log(shiftedDiff("isn't", "'tisn"))
console.log(shiftedDiff("Esham", "Esham"))
console.log(shiftedDiff("dog", "god"))
```